# Svg doesn't show up on deployed webpage

Tags: html, reactjs, deployment

```html
<img src="/src/assets/logo-bookmark-white.svg" alt="" />
```

I am using an svg like this. When I open the page on localhost everything works, but when I deploy the page on vercel or netlify, all of the svgs which are source of an img tag disappear.

I checked the path, there is nothing wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `<img src="./src/assets/logo-bookmark-white.svg" alt="" />` or need to upload on imgur to use the link for your project, that's what Im doing :/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).